# How to connect dots with lines in Scatter Plot or some other Plot?

Tags: orange

Subj.

Given the following in Scatter Plot:

```
     .

.  .   .
```

How to get something like:

```
     .
    / \
.__.   .
```

?

Comment: Could you tell more about the problem and the environment you are working in? A casual reader might think that the problem can be fixed by copy-pasting.

Comment: How would you know which instances to connect and which to leave disconnected?

Comment: I assume that they should be connected in the order they exist in data table (corresponding to feature that is used as X axis). I will have a look for Line Chart, which you mentioned in the answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps have a look at MDS (multi-dimensional scaling) widget, Line Chart widget (from Timeseries add-on), or Network Explorer widget (from Networks add-on).

[image]